# addTarget to UIRefreshControl()

Tags: ios, swift, uirefreshcontrol

I have made a `UIRefreshControl`:

```
refresher = UIRefreshControl()
refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "refresh")
refresher.addTarget(self, action: "refreshed", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
refresher.addTarget(self, action: "refreshed", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ApplicationReserved)
refresher.addTarget(self, action: "refreshed", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents."scrolled down to bottom")
```

It is a refresher and works fine, but I want to add an action which will make it refresh when I scroll down to the bottom of my `tableView`, something like I have done with `ValueChanged`, but for the bottom

Comment: You would need to use the scroll view delegate methods on your table view to make your own. `UIRefreshControl` does not know when your table view has reached the bottom. Maybe something in `scrollViewDidScroll(_:)` that checks if the `contentOffset` indicates the table view has scrolled to the bottom.

Comment: @ShaohaoLin: Please don't suggest edits where you add "Thanks" to a post. This is [fluff that should be edited out](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260778/2675154).

Comment: yes thanks, for answering this, and many of my other questions too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built in `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let bottomEdge = scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height
    if bottomEdge >= scrollView.contentSize.height {
        // Reached bottom, do your refresh
        print("Bottom")
    }
}
```

When the `scrollView` has ended it´s decelerating and you´re at the bottom, then you can call your `refresher`.